# .Net TextBox With AutoComplete and custom sorting (not alphabetical)

Tags: .net, sorting, textbox

I'm searching for a TextBox Control with the default AutoComplete Feature, but the entries in the suggestion shold sorted like the items in the list.

for example...

List Items:

```
ab  
ac  
aa  
bb
```

If I type the letter "a" to the TextBox, the suggested items shold sorted like this:

```
ab  
ac  
aa
```

NOT like this:

```
aa  
ab  
ac
```

Is there a way to disable the automatically sorting?

Answer (score 2):

.NET's AutoComplete functionality merely wraps Win32's [SHAutoComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  There is no ability to modify the order results are presented in.