# Order for autocomplete

Tags: c#, linq, autocomplete

Let's say that we have a collection of `Human`s:

```
public class Human
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

var people = new List<Human>(){...};
```

How can we implement autocomplete while sorting people first by `FirstName` then by `SecondName` and then by `CompanyName`?

I tried:

```
people.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(term) || x.SecondName.StartsWith(term) 
  ||  x.CompanyName.StartsWith(term))
  .OrderBy(x => x.FirstName).ThenBy(x => x.SecondName).ThenBy(x => x.CompanyName)
```

But that doesn't work correctly. I want to see only all matched `FirstName` fields at first then only `SecondName` fields and so on.

Comment: Despite all those upvotes, none of the solutions will actually change the order of an AutoComplete dropdown. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821206/net-textbox-with-autocomplete-and-custom-sorting-not-alphabetical)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
people.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(term)).OrderBy(x => x.FirstName)
.Concat(people.Where(x => x.SecondName.StartsWith(term)).OrderBy(x => x.SecondName))
.Concat(people.Where(x => x.CompanyName.StartsWith(term)).OrderBy(x => x.CompanyName))
```

Add `.Distinct()` to the end or not depending on whether you want to exclude cases where one person is matched more than one way (in such a case you could also use `.Union()` instead of `.Concat()` depending on your source - it's documented as preserving order with enumerable sources, but not with other queryable sources, so it could mess up the ordering depending on the source of `people`).

Comment: I see someone gave the same answer and deleted it. I think they were correct except in describing it as "three different queries", it's a single query in their answer, though it has other queries as steps in creating that query, only one query is actually executed.

Comment: I prefer this to my answer, if I'm honest.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'll want

```
people.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(term) ||
                  x.SecondName.StartsWith(term) ||
                  x.CompanyName.StartsWith(term))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(term))
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.SecondName.StartsWith(term))
    .ThenBy(x => x.FirstName)
    .ThenBy(x => x.SecondName)
    .ThenBy(x => x.CompanyName)
```

This puts

- Everyone whose first name matches first
- Then everyone whose second name matches
- (Then, there'll be everyone whose company name matches)
- Within this order, it'll then sort by first/last/company name as before.

The yes/no sorts need `Descending` as `false` is less than `true`.

You could possibly optimise this slightly by `Select`ing an anonymous class with the person and three bools for `FirstNameMatches`, `SecondNameMatches` etc., then use these bools in the `Where` and ordering clauses, thus avoiding calling `StartsWith` 5 times instead of 3, but you can worry about that when you have the basic sort working.

It'll be trickier if you want to sort the second-name matches by second-name and the company-name matches by company name.

Comment: Yeah, I just went with "add some lines to the existing query" rather than "rewrite it properly" ;)

Comment: Although I don't think it's inefficient enough to merit a downvote :-/

Comment: Certainly not. Against a DB source I'd expect it to be much the same performance as any other. In memory, it's hard to predict which would be better. If I really wanted to give a lot of effort to performance, I'd take yours (single filter, unlike mine) and roll the ordering into a single ordering against a custom comparer.

Comment: Then again, if I really wanted a lot of performance, I might preload a prefix look-up and skip any linq-based solution entirely (except perhaps in the query to fill it). Given the use-case being autocomplete, that might actually be the way to go, since slight delays become very noticeable with autocomplete.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for that. Selective not-use of LINQ may well be the best way to do this.

Comment: I'm vaguely curious to know which of your and my approach would win in raw performance matters, just because it was brought up. I suspect though that it's likely that it would depend not just on the size of the data, but also the distribution of the different fields, so there could be data-sets for which one was faster and data-sets for which the other was.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake that you are doing is that you use `ThenBy()` after `OrderBy()`. Using this you are reordering internally the already ordered list without ordering by whether property matches.

What you should do is filter the list in the three ways and then join them and remove duplicates using `Union()`.

So what about:

```
people.Where( x => x.FirstName.StartsWith( term ) ).OrderBy( x => x.FirstName )
      .Union( people.Where( x => x.SecondName.StartsWith( term ) ).OrderBy( x => x.SecondName ) )
      .Union( people.Where( x => x.CompanyName.StartsWith( term ) ).OrderBy( x => x.CompanyName ) );
```

---

**EDIT :**

As pointed out *Jon Hanna* this could not work if you use `Queryable.Union()` because it doesn't preserve the order of the query:

> Enumerable.Union() is specified as preserving order but
>   Queryable.Union() is not. A given implementation could, but it doesn't
>   have to and another (or an update to the same one) might not. The code
>   given could therefore give the results in any order at all, if people
>   is not an in-memory source. Jon Hanna

Comment: This is exactly what `ThenBy` is for - adding a secondary ordering after a primary ordering. The _mistake_ is ordering by name rather than whether-name-matches.

Comment: +1 Yes, I know that. I mean that he shouldn't use `ThenBy()` in this  case. I'll edit my answer so thank you for the clafirication.

Comment: `Enumerable.Union()` is specified as preserving order but `Queryable.Union()` is not. A given implementation could, but it doesn't have to and another (or an update to the same one) might not. The code given could therefore give the results in any order at all, if `people` is not an in-memory source.

Comment: You're right but I considered the basic case where he has an `Enumerable.Union()` (in this case he's using a List as specified in the question).

Comment: Yep. I do think it's important to point out the cases where they differ, for the next person thinking "ah, that's exactly like my problem".

Comment: Ok thank you, to avoid that I'll add what you said to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for adding it. I've never asked a question on this site, but I've had mine answered here a lot, because I've been that person going "ah, that's exactly like my problem" :)

Comment: Yep you're completely right. It happened to me too. Infact sometime clarifications and specifications are very helpful.